# Why is the latest version of noobs not working on my raspberry pi 4?

Tags: pi-4, noobs

Hello when i try to boot up with a fresh install of the latest vertion of noobs it just shows a rainbow screen.

What do  do to fix this?

Comment: Are you using NOOBS 3.5.0 from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/? Do you really need the multi-boot capability? If you do, then use PINN https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=142574 as it's an enhanced version. To get started you should probably forget NOOBS and just use the RPi Imager tool to write RaspiOS directly to your SDCard.

Comment: I will give PINN a go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using NOOBS 3.5.0 from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/?

Do you really need the multi-boot capability? If you do, then use PINN https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=142574 as it's an enhanced version.

To get started you should probably forget NOOBS and just use the RPi Imager tool to write plain simple RaspiOS directly to your SDCard.

Comment: I do like to have multi boot capability and i have tried to boot from a SD card containing noobs 3.50.

Comment: It still has the same problem when i used pinn.